# Cannot Run Python From VisualStudioCode Terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So my pc was running as default a 32 bit python version, but I wanted to run the 64 bit that I had installed. But when I try to run python from my VSCode Terminal this is the result:

```
Javier Camacho@DESKTOP-9V7BRO5 MINGW64 /d/Javier Camacho Data/Escritorio/SS Progra/pruebas python
$ python
bash: /c/Users/Javier Camacho/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python: Permission denied
```

and now I can't even run pip, because the same thing shows up:

```
Javier Camacho@DESKTOP-9V7BRO5 MINGW64 /d/Javier Camacho Data/Escritorio/SS Progra/pruebas python
$ pip -v
bash: /c/Users/Javier Camacho/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/pip: Permission denied
```

my computer runs windows 10. I have tried uninstalling all my python versions and installing them again but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Could you run `ls -l $(which python)` and show the result?

Comment: It seems that you install python from Microsoft Store.Try to get it from python.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set python path in your computer

Right click on My Computer ->Properties ->Advanced System setting ->Environment Variable ->New

In Variable name write path and in Variable value copy path up to C://Python(i.e., path where Python is installed). Click Ok ->Ok.

Comment: Turns out that after doing thins it didn't work but I tried using the command py instead of python worked.

Answer (score 0):

use `sudo` in prefix, Like..

- `sudo python`
- `sudo pip -v`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that what git bash needed to find was the conda environment. You need to type `conda init bash` on the git bash console, close it, and then open it again. It should activate the conda base environment by itself and you can work from there.